# How this recursive function returns a value to main?

Tags: c, recursion

I've spent hours trying to figure out why this recursive function works even when the `return` statement is only inside the `if` (base case).

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main( void )
{
    int sum_recursive_function( int const number_copy );//function prototype

    int number, sum_recursive;

    puts( "Please type a number and I will add its digits:" );
    scanf( "%d", &number );

    sum_recursive = sum_recursive_function( number );
    printf( "%s%d\n", "The sum of the digits is: ", sum_recursive );
}

int sum_recursive_function( int const number_copy )
{
    int last_digit, sum_pre = 0;
    if( number_copy == 0 ){
        return sum_pre;
    }
    else{
        last_digit = number_copy % 10;
        sum_pre = last_digit + sum_recursive_function( number_copy / 10 );
    }
}
```

I understand this:
If I type the number 1, the `if` inside the function checks if `number_copy` is equal to 0, as it is not, it gets into the else statment, then the remainder of 1 divided by 10 = 1 is assigned to `last_digit`. `Last_digit` (1) is added with the recursive call which sends 1/10=0 to `sum_recursive_function`. This time `sum_recursive_function` checks if the argument is equal to 0, and as it is equal to 0, it returns `sum_pre` as 0. `Sum_pre` is = 1 + 0. And then I DO NOT UNDERSTAND how is that `sum_recursive_function` returns `Sum_pre` (1) to main.

Comment: If you don't specify a return value and control passes out the end of the function, many compilers will return whatever happens to be on the stack -- in this case it will be the last value calculated, sum_pre.  This is undefined behavior, though-- you should always use a return statement to pass a value out of your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code exhibits **undefined behavior**. `sum_recursive_function()` needs to always return a value.

Let's fix it:

```
int sum_recursive_function(int const number_copy)
{
    if (number_copy == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        int last_digit = number_copy % 10;
        return last_digit + sum_recursive_function( number_copy / 10 );
    }
}
```

Perhaps correct code will allow you to understand this better.

Comment: So I don't need sum_pre at all, and I return the whole thing at once from the else statement. Its clear now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Actually even as it is originally defined the `sum_recursive_function` always returns a value.

Let me try to explain the recursion that is happening on this row (this where the *magic* is):

```
sum_pre = last_digit + sum_recursive_function( number_copy / 10 );
```

Assume the input parameter is the number: 12345
Check those iterration:

```
1. sum_pre = 5 + sum_recursive_function( 1234 );
2. sum_pre = 5 + 4 + sum_recursive_function( 123 );
3. sum_pre = 5 + 4 + 3 + sum_recursive_function( 12 );
4. sum_pre = 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + sum_recursive_function( 1 );
5. sum_pre = 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 + 0;
```

On the first step the value of last_digit is 5, on the next it is 4, then 3, then 2, then 1.
At the iteration #5 the recursion ends.

I hope this helps to better understand the recursion!

Answer (score 2):

The reason the code works even without a return statement (which is in this case by accident) is because by the x86 calling convention the return value of a function (more specifically an integer or a pointer) is stored in the EAX register. So whatever value was last in the EAX register is taken as the return value of the function once the function exists.

You can test this by appending this inline assembly to the end of the recursive function.

```
asm ("mov $5, %eax");
```

Now your program will always print 5 instead of the actual sum.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions